# Isolate scope - access scope attributes on element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

When creating a directive with isolate scope, I can't access scope properties on the directive element (it's was not the case in angular 1.0.7, but in later versions (e.g. 1.2.17)).

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("red", function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.isRed = true;
    }
  };
});
```

---

```
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

---

```
<div red ng-class="{red: isRed}">This is red in angular 1.0.7</div>
```

---

```
<div red ng-class="{red: isRed}">This is NOT red in angular 1.2.17</div>
```

[See demo.](http://jsbin.com/xedevu/4/edit)

So, is there a way to access scope properties on the directive element itself, not just on their parent elements in angular 1.0.7+?

I know I can use some workarounds, but what would be a "clear" solution to this?

Comment: If the only purpose of directive is to add a class named `red` to your div, then you can follow this approach. 
    `link: function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        element.addClass("red");
    }`

Comment: Thanks @Siraj - Yeah, this is what I'm doing now, but would love to understand the why behind the problem.

Comment: shows you two options below, what do you like between the two? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you tried to isolate the scope, try:

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("foo", function() {
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-class='{red: isRed}'><ng-transclude/></div>",
    link: function(scope,element) {
      scope.isRed = true;

    }
  };
});
```

Your code is trying to use the parent's scope's "isRed", and your directive is actually setting a child scope's "isRed".

### As an alternative to the above

initialize an object:

```
<div ng-init="color={red:true}"></div>
```

use the directive like so:

```
<div foo ng-class="color">Hello world</div>
```

see the ngClass "=":

```
angular.module("app", []).directive("foo", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      ngClass: "="
    },
    link: function(scope,element) {
      scope.ngClass.red = true;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that totally makes sense. But it's strange, this was working in earlier versions, but I don't think that the concept of isolate scope actually changed.

Comment: it was probably a bug in the earlier versions; am glad it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you replace the scope.isRed with a function rather than just setting the value of true.

```
scope.isRed = function() {
 return true;
}
```

I'm not sure why this has changed from the earlier version of Angular, but it makes sense to use a function, rather than direct assignment.

Comment: Hey. Checked it out, but not working for me: Is this what you mean: http://jsbin.com/fuviy/1/edit.

Comment: I've edited the bin here http://jsbin.com/tapifocuxaqu/1/edit and it works, without overriding the scope. Note that the $scope is injected in the link function.

Comment: In your demo, the scope is not isolated. With isolated scope it doesn't work. http://jsbin.com/tapifocuxaqu/3/edit

Comment: I see what you mean. Have you read this article: [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) ? I think that by isolating the scope you will only be able to set the flag using either the model or the $parent to store the property. See an updated bin here http://jsbin.com/tapifocuxaqu/8/